# combine two or more conditions in one if statement

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Can we combine two or more conditions in one if statement?
I know that in C# we can combine two or more conditions in an IF statement. Can we do it in Delphi?

I have to check whether the user entered a value for the three Edit controls in the form. 
Thanks for all the help

Comment: Every programming language I know of, and that's over 200, has some form of boolean logic, involving the operations AND, OR, and NOT.  If you haven't seen those yet, you really need to read a book. In fact if you did it in C# why not just try it in delphi?  THe only difference is that in Delphi parenthesis are not always required with an IF statement.  But when making multiple equality comparisons, you should write `if (a = b) or (c = d)` for example.

Comment: Additional. you need to consider also that there are some condition need to be group in a parenthesis like if ((a=x1) and (b=y1)) or ((a=x2) and (a=y2)) then do something.

Answer (score 19):

The general form of conditional statement is :

**IF** "**Logical expression**" **THEN** ...**ELSE** ...

The **"Logical expression"** is any *boolean expression*. A boolean expression is an expression can be evaluated as TRUE or FALSE.

A boolean expression can be constructed using *comparison operators* and *boolean operators*.

Comparison operators:

```
=   equals
<>  not equals
>   greater than
>=  greater than or equals
<   less than
<=  less than or equals
```

Set Comparison operators:

```
=   equals
<=  returns true, if set1 is a subset of set2
>=  returns true, if set1 is a superset of set2
in  returns true, if an element is in the set
```

Boolean operators:

```
AND    logical and
OR     logical or
NOT    logical not
XOR    logical exclusive disjucntion
```

Examples:

```
IF A = 10 THEN ...
IF A >= B THEN ... 
IF C or D THEN ... (Note: C and D have to be logical, i.e. TRUE or FALSE)
IF NOT E THEN ...  (Note: E has to be logical, i.e. TRUE or FALSE)
```

C, D and E can be replace with any logical expression, for example:

```
IF (edit1.text = '') OR ( ISEMPTY( edit2.text ) ) THEN ...
IF NOT checkbox1.checked THEN ...
```

Note that logical expression can be constructed from simpler logical expressions by using boolean operators, for examples:

```
IF ( A = 10 ) AND ( A >= B ) THEN ...
IF NOT ( ( A = 10 ) AND ( A >= B ) ) THEN ...
```

Common mistake in writing logical expression is not paying attention of operator precedence (which operator evaluated first). The boolean operators have higher precedence than comparison operators, for example:

```
IF A = 10 OR A >= B THEN ...
```

The above is wrong because Delphi tries to evaluate

`10 OR A` first, instead of

`A = 10`. If A itself is not a logical expression, then error occurs.

The solution is by using brackets, so the above IF...THEN...should be written as:

`IF (A = 10) OR (A >= B) THEN ...`

For checking 3 edit controls, the conditional statement becomes:

`IF ( Edit1.text <> '' ) AND ( Edit2.text <> '' ) AND ( Edit3.text <> '' ) THEN ...`

Note: Slightly off topic, but related. Free components TJvValidators, TJvValidationSummary and TJvErrorIndicator from [Jedi JVCL project](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) provide a nice validation mechanism.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but please don't use all caps for keywords. That is so 1950s.

Comment: I added `<>` to your list of operators.

Comment: `in` should be there too, but I don't know how to summarize it in less than 3 words...

Comment: I added XOR to Boolean operators

Answer (score 11):

Of course. You can do something like:

```
if (A > 7) and (B < 13) or (C in [2, 4, 7]) then
```

Or for the Edit controls:

```
if (Edit1.Text <> '') and (Edit2.Text <> '') and (Edit3.Text <> '') then
```

or, if that is what you want:

```
if (Edit1.Text = '') or (Edit2.Text = '') or (Edit3.Text = '') then
```

etc.etc.

It might be beneficial to actually read a book about Delphi, for instance the Delphi Language Guide, which comes with each version of Delphi (in the help, in the References part) or [can be found online](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index).

For the question: in general, you can combine different conditions using `and`, `or` and `not`. To avoid problems with operator precedence, you should usually put each condition in parentheses, as I did above.

Comment: They can go into a very complex statement with parentheses too, for example, `if ((A > 7) or ((B = 'abc') and not (C = 'def')) or (D <> 8)) and (R > 8) then ...` (Speaking of which `<>` is just like `!=` in other languages like C#)

Comment: Personally I always use ()s when logical operations are involved.  It's safer than trying to keep the rules straight between multiple languages.  The compiler will produce the same code anyway, there's no harm in using them when they aren't needed.

Answer (score 8):

You must use the `And` and `Or` operators to combine conditions in a [if sentence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#If_Statements)

```
 if (Edit1.Text<>'') and (Edit2.Text<>'') and (Edit3.Text<>'') then
```

Answer (score 6):

It's very important to remember that expressions are evaluated left to right.

In this example:

```
if False and SomeFunction() then
```

`SomeFunction()` will not be called.
If you turn them around:

```
if SomeFunction() and False then
```

`SomeFunction()` will be called.

Comment: This is an important answer, all the other answers are very obvious.

Comment: This depends on [Boolean short-circuit evaluation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsbooleanshortcircuitevaluation_xml.html) `{$B}`/`{$BOOLEVAL}` by default it is set to `OFF`. but if it is set to `ON` the `SomeFunction` will be evaluated in the first example.

Comment: @kobik you're right. But if anytime a developer would set this on, I would hunt him down and question his sanity.

Answer (score 1):

When using `if not` then:

```
if not ( (edit1.Text = '2') or (edit2.Text = '3') ) then ...
```